# Convert multiple dtypes in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dtype

I am having issues concat-ing 2 dataframes together, and I think it is because their dtypes are different.

dataframe 'df' has been read in from a site (json.loads of some response.content), dataframe 2 'old_df' is the same data, but was pd.to_csv()'ed  and then pd.read_csv()'ed

Now their dtypes are different (see below). Is there anyway I can:

- Stop the dtypes from changing in the first place
- Change them back (easily), or get them to match
  OR
- Get append() or concat() to not care about dtype?

```
df.dtypes
Out[2]: 
0     object
1     object
2     object
3     object
4     object
5     object
6     object
7     object
8     object
9     object
10    object
11    object
12    object
13    object
dtype: object
old_df.dtypes
Out[3]: 
0      object
1      object
2      object
3      object
4      object
5      object
6      object
7     float64
8       int64
9       int64
10      int64
11     object
12     object
13     object
dtype: object
```

Comment: `concat()` works fine with different dtypes, so i guess there's some other issue with the data: `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([1,2]), pd.DataFrame(['a','b'])])`

Comment: thanks, the way i solved this is to write and read to/from csv the new df, just so pandas would apply the same blackbox hocus pocus conversion to that, now it concats normally

Answer (score 0):

Rather than to write/read to/from csv file, you can apply `dtypes` from `old_df` to `df`, especially if you have a large number of rows in `df`:

```
>>> df.astype(old_df.dtypes).dtypes
0      object
1      object
2      object
3      object
4      object
5      object
6      object
7     float64
8       int64
9       int64
10      int64
11     object
12     object
13     object
dtype: object
```